# Getting day number in the week in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, datetime, stored-procedures

How can I get the number of a day in a week fro example:

```
2009-10-21 would be 4 assuming that:

Sun - 1
Mon - 2
Tue - 3
Wed - 4
Thu - 5
Fri - 6
Sat - 7
```

I am using MySql Server 5.0.37

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT`[`DAYOFWEEK`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/date-and-time-functions.html)`('2009-10-13')`